# The best season of all

Tags: riddle, seasonal

> - I am the best of all seasons.
> - Some might not care about me but many are fanatics when it comes to me.
> - Some love me so much that they are willing to remove their clothes and put on makeup for me.
> - At my peak, you might even see famous people stripping by mistake on purpose!
> - No matter how much people like me, at my peak, people only want to take breaks from me.

Comment: Is "striping" in the fourth bullet point a typo for "stripping" or is it deliberate?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan thanks, that was my mistake.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for gracing me with their loving downvotes, don't hesitate to leave a **comment** on your way out. :)

Comment: Didn't you mean to say 'put on makeup for me'? Also you combined 'by mistake' with 'on purpose'. Did you mean to do this?

Comment: @wildBillMunson Thanks for the correction. The second one is on purpose. it is about a controversy that happened a few years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> Football season.

The first clue is an opinion, and the second clue could apply to virtually any season.

The third clue is

> A reference to fans who take off their shirts and cover themselves with body paint with their team's colors.

The fourth clue is

> A reference to the infamous "wardrobe malfunction" involving Justin Timberlake and Janet Jackson during the halftime show at Super Bowl XXXVIII (The Super Bowl is the 'peak' of the season).

The fifth clue is

> A reference to the commercial breaks during the Super Bowl. Many people are more interested in the commercials than the game itself.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. As for the breaks, I was referring to the extremely expensive and famous super ball commercials.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense!! :)

Comment: There are many other sports which fit all the clues. e.g. [IPL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Premier_League) Though +1 for a good fit.

Comment: When I saw this question I suspected this might be the answer, but I could also make baseball fit fairly well.

Comment: I edited my answer to bring it more in line with the OP's intentions.